# Heuristics for the Hodge Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, ho.history-overview

[W. V. D. Hodge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._V._D._Hodge) is famous for his Hodge conjecture, one of the Millennium prize problems. Hodge might have had some rough heuristics or ideas that led him to the formulation of the conjecture.

I am looking for the history and background behind the formulation of Hodge Conjecture. How did Hodge arrive at his conjecture?

**Hodge Conjecture ( What I understood after reading Dan Freed's article ) :**

> On a complex projective manifold $\mathbb{X}$, a topological cycle $\mathfrak{C}$ ( on $\mathbb{X}$ ) is homologous to a rational combination of algebraic cycles iff $\mathfrak{C}$ has rotation number $0$. ( Rotation number $e^{i\theta}$ on differential form, volumes are invariant under rotation).

**Hodge Conjecture (Deligne's description):**

> On a projective non-singular algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, any Hodge class is a rational combination of classes $\rm{cl(\mathbb{Z})}$ of algebraic cycles.

**The things that interest me:**

1. How are Freed's version and Deligne's version versions equivalent?
2. How did Hodge arrive at that conclusion? Were there heuristic reasons or intuitive arguments that gives him some hope for a conjecture in that direction? .
3. How can one state an analogue of the Hodge conjecture in number theory?  Are there any attempts to formulate an analogue in that case?

I am curious to hear answers, even if highly technical in nature.

Comment: Do you happen to know "Peter" on a first-name basis?  Also, are you planning to ask for heuristics behind many more conjectures?

Comment: @Shanmukha_Srinivasan: "curios" should be "$\text{curious}$".


Comment: Actually Swinnerton-Dyer doesn't stand on ceremony, despite the baronetcy. But the first name is unclear.

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: It's worth looking at Hodge's original ICM article. The "conjecture"
was announced with little fanfare... (2) He certainly knew of Lefschetz's $(1,1)$ theorem, so I suppose that this was a natural extrapolation. (3) Some people consider Tate's conjecture that the Galois invariant part of $\ell$-adic cohomology is spanned by algebraic cycles to be an analogue. If you search for "Hodge conjecture" here, you'll find a number of useful discussions.

Comment: See for example,
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54197/why-is-the-hodge-conjecture-so-important
and
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17020/why-do-people-think-that-abelian-varieties-are-the-hardest-case-for-the-hodge-con

Comment: Thank you Charles, Donu and Chandu, for your editing and references.

Comment: @Donu- I believe in the Proceedings of a Conference on Arithmetical Algebraic Geometry held at Purdue Tate says that he doesn't think the two conjectures are particularly connected.  I can look up exact reference if you wish.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best answer I can imagine for a question like this is to quote the man himself:
"The second result of Lefschetz tells us that a necessary and sufficient condition
that a 2-cycle $\Gamma_2$ in $V_2$ be algebraic... This result has many geometrical applications...
It is clearly a matter of great importance to extend Lefschetz's condition for a
2-cycle to be algebraic. The general problem is as follows...."

See  page 184 of
the [Proceedings of the ICM 1950](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1950.1/ICM1950.1.ocr.pdf)
for the full statement:

*Hodge, W. V. D.*, The topological invariants of algebraic varieties, Proc. Intern. Congr. Math. (Cambridge, Mass., Aug. 30-Sept. 6, 1950) 1, 182-192 (1952). [ZBL0048.41701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0048.41701).

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**: One point is that Hodge's original version of the conjecture was wrong, and in a couple of ways.  You do need rational coefficients (integral is too much to ask for, see ref below). Also a more general conjecture of Hodge fails: see

http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/HodgeConj.pdf

for one of all the all-time great disrespectful titles. (Hodge was a major innovator in algebraic geometry and complex manifold theory: but his theory needed plenty of work, particularly I think from Kodaira, before it became clear foundationally. The same is true, perhaps in spades, for Lefschetz.)

**Edit**: At the level of linear algebra, Hodge theory deals with a vector space with a double grading. Using the heuristic grading = concept of homogeneity, the subspaces of (p,p) type in Hodge theory can be picked out by the use of the circle group, as Freed does. Really (pun intended) there is a bigger group with two dimensions involved, the group of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication. A shallow remark is that these two groups control the linear algebra in Hodge theory. A deeper remark is that the vector spaces involved also have a rational structure, coming from the concept of integral cycle in topology. The interaction of the groups with the rational structure isn't shallow at all.

Comment: The error corrected in Grothendieck's paper was not the issue of integer versus rational coefficients -- this was corrected in Atiyah and Hirzebruch, "Algebraic Cycles on Complex Manifolds", Topology 1 (1962) p. 25-45 . Grothendieck's correction concerned a conjectural characterization of those classes in $H_k(X)$ which are pushed forward from some algebraic $Y \subset X$ with $\dim Y=m$. (The case h=2m$ being the Hodge conjecture.)

Comment: Thank you David, Charles. The error was made clear now. +1, both to your comments and answer

Comment: Of course, I meant $k=2m$, not $h=2m$, in my comment.

Comment: And the title is "Analytic cycles..." not "Algebraic cycles...". MR0145560